# Google Bigquery error while querying from python api

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a query that works in the console cloud google platform:

```
select visitorId 
from `data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801` as ga,  UNNEST(ga.hits) AS hits
```

I need to execute it in a python code, if I try to execute this using the google-api-python-client (v 1.5.0), I always get errors:

1 -

```
select fullVisitorId FROM [data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801] as ga, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
```

I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project-id/queries?alt=json
>   returned "Not found: Table project-id:data-set-id.hits">

2 -

```
select fullVisitorId FROM [data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801] as ga,UNNEST(ga.hits) AS hits
```

I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project-id/queries?alt=json
>   returned "Not found: Dataset project-id:ga">

3 -

```
select fullVisitorId FROM [data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801] as ga, UNNEST(ga_sessions_20180801.hits) AS hits
```

I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project-id/queries?alt=json
>   returned "Not found: Dataset
>   project-id:ga_sessions_20180801">

4 -

```
select fullVisitorId FROM [data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801] as ga, UNNEST(data-set-id.ga_sessions_20180801.hits) AS hits
```

I get:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project-id/queries?alt=json
>   returned "Encountered "" at line 4, column 24.">

code I use to call this:

```
bigquery_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build( 'bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials) 
bigquery_service.jobs().query( projectId=self.project_id, body={"maxResults": max_results, "defaultDataset": {"projectId": self.project_id, "datasetId": data_set_id}, "query": query})
```

I've tried some more things but with the same result... Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run the query through the UI? What is the actual Python code that you are using?

Comment: No, as I mentioned that query works in the UI. 
And the python code that i use is, as i mentioned, the python client: 

bigquery_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

bigquery_service.jobs().query(
            projectId=self.project_id,
            body={"maxResults": max_results,
                  "defaultDataset": {"projectId": self.project_id,
                                     "datasetId": data_set_id},
                  "query": query})

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you are using instead of putting it in a comment. Is there a reason that you are using the API in this way instead of something like [the example from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-python)?

Comment: because i have to use that API (not personal choice), I'm trying to run a sample with the example from the documentation, but I would rather use the other API which is the one that the project is using

Comment: Could you post the full code snippet while removing personal information (project, dataset names, any keys or other sensitive information) ? The error at example 4 suggest a particular location where we should look at. Also, if you do a simple query, like SELECT * FROM [xxxx] LIMIT 5, will it return the same error message as in number 4?